# Having trouble creating two shortcodes, one for logged in user and one for visitors

Tags: php, functions, customization, shortcode, login

So I'm trying to create a code (in `functions.php`) that displays a widget content, from shortcode, based on whether the user is logged in or logged out (visitor). I am successful in displaying content for logged in users, but not for visitors, as I need everything to happen in the same widget. The approach I'm trying is by using two different shortcodes, like this:

```
[member_only]You are logged in.[/member_only]
[visitor_only]Login / Register[/visitor_only]
```

If user is logged in, it displays the content of

```
[member_only]You are logged in.[/member_only]
```

If user is logged out, it displays the content of

```
[visitor_only]Login / Register[/visitor_only]
```

My code:

```
/* BEGIN LOGIN BUTTON WIDGET SHORTCODE */


function member_only_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_null($content) && !is_feed()) {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_shortcode('member_only', 'member_only_shortcode');

function visitor_only_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_null($content) && !is_feed()) {
        return "";
    }
else {
    return $content; }

}
add_shortcode('visitor_only', 'visitor_only_shortcode');


/* END LOGIN BUTTON WIDGET SHORTCODE */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code exactly as you put it in your question works fine for me and does exactly what you suggested.

To make it work I had to make sure my WP post editor was in code editor mode as HTML or Visual Editor may create extra problems:

[image]

And this is what my test code in the post editor looked like, when I had a successful test:

```
<!-- wp:html -->
<p>this is the content</p>

<p>more content 
[member_only]You are logged in.[/member_only]
[visitor_only]Login / Register[/visitor_only]
</p>

<!-- /wp:html -->
```

You can make the second shortcode a bit clearer to read by adding `!` for 'not' on the front of the first condition, then the structure is the same as the first shortcode, and you don't need the `else`:

```
function visitor_only_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_null($content) && !is_feed()) {
       return $content;
    }
}

add_shortcode('visitor_only', 'visitor_only_shortcode');
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the site was changing the language in the testing browser, that's because I'm using Polylang plugin. But anyway, can you tell me if I should leave the ` if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_null($content) && !is_feed()) {
        return "";
    }` like that? The `return=""` part, is there another way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Yeah your logic there is kind of strange, I'll make an example which will simplify it for you

Comment: Added code example for second shortcode which is a bit cleaner

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much, everything is way better now.